# MongoDB: Why isn't my findOneAndUpdate query deleting items by ID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete a matched ID from my MongoDB database using findOneAndUpdate and the $pull operator, but nothing is being deleted. To investigate, I logged the foundList item and it returned null. I think there may be a problem with the way I'm writing the ID section, because in my database the ID field is written as _id: ObjectId("numbers"), but I'm just passing a string of numbers. Could this be the problem?

Here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  const listName = req.body.listName;

  if (listName === "Today") {
    Item.deleteOne({ _id: checkedItemId })
      .then(() => console.log("Selected item deleted successfully!"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    console.log(id);
    Item.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: listName },
      { $pull: { items: { _id: checkedItemId } } }
    ).then((foundList) => {
      console.log(foundList);
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});
```

I suspect that the problem may be with the way I'm passing the ID to $pull. Is there a way to convert the string of numbers to an ObjectId before passing it to $pull? Or is there another issue that could be causing my query to fail? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Addition:
Here's my Item schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

export { Item };
export { itemSchema };
```

Comment: Can you post the `Item` schema declaration?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did it, sorry for the delay i was abroad

Comment: `Item.findOneAndUpdate` to `List.findOneAndUpdate`